# Mensaje de Excepción luego de cargar todos los datos en tabla de SQL Server

Tags: vb.net

Intentare ser lo mas explicito posible.

Estoy intentando ingresar datos a dos tablas en SQL Server. La composición de las tablas las cuales se conectan mediante el `NumeroDeOrden` son de la siguiente manera.

**La primer tabla** `OrdenesDeCompraCON` ingresa los datos generales e importes totales del conjunto de producto que tiene dentro en una sola linea de la tabla.

**La segunda tabla** `OrdenesDeCompraEXION` ingresa los datos de cada y uno de los productos que contiene una orden de compra separando a estos en una linea distinta de la tabla.

**Para identificar el producto** 3 que corresponde a la orden de compra numero 1000 lo hago de esta forma `1000-3`

Imagen de las tablas de SQL Server
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden obvservar hay unas filas que no se llenan como `FinalizadoPor`, `FechaDeFinalizacion`, `EditadoPor`  y `FechaDeEdicion`. Esto ocurre porque estas Ordenes entran en estado de Pendientes y cuando el material que compran se recibe pueden pasar a finalizadas por eso debo guardar el estado en el que se encuentran y esas celdas se completaran una vez que el circuito finalice.

Entonces tengo las tablas funcionando correctamente, el ingreso de información a esas tablas también lo hace perfectamente ya que todo los items que cargo previamente en un DataGridView se cargan satisfactoriamente en la base de datos tengo un mensaje de `excepcion` el cual se lanza cuando termina de cargar absolutamente todo antes no pasa. por mas cantidad de items cargue en simultaneo.

Imagen con el mensaje de `Excepcion`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
`La leyenda de la excepcion es "The parameterized Query (@numerodeorden nvarchar(1), @item nvarchar(3), @producto nvarchar expect the parameter @producto, which was not supplied.`
Y por ultimo este es mi codigo

```
Sub AgregarOrden()

    Dim conn As New SqlConnection
    conn.ConnectionString = conexion



    ruta = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO OrdenesDeCompraCON (numerodeorden, fecha, estado, proveedor,iva, importetotalconiva, importetotalsiniva, lugardeentrega, fechadeentrega, formadepago, acreditacion, NotaGeneral, creadopor, fechadecreacion, FinalizadoPor, FechaDeFinalizacion) values (@numerodeorden, @fecha, @estado, @proveedor,@iva, @importetotalconiva, @importetotalsiniva, @lugardeentrega, @fechadeentrega, @formadepago, @acreditacion, @NotaGeneral, @creadopor, @fechadecreacion, @FinalizadoPor, @FechaDeFinalizacion)", Conn)

    Dim filas As DataGridViewRowCollection = aodcdt.Rows
    Try
        Conn.Open()
        'For Each Row In filas

        ruta.Parameters.Clear()
        ruta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numerodeorden", Convert.ToString(aodcordendecompra))
        ruta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha", Convert.ToString(aodcfechahoy))
        ruta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@estado", Convert.ToString("PENDIENTE"))
        ruta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@proveedor", Convert.ToString(aodcrazonsocial))
        ruta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iva", Convert.ToString(aodciva))
        ruta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@importetotalconiva", Convert.ToString(aodcimportesiniva))
        ruta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@importetotalsiniva", Convert.ToString(aodcimporteconiva))
        ruta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lugardeentrega", Convert.ToString(aodclugardeentrega))
        ruta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fechadeentrega", Convert.ToString(aodcfechadeentrega))
        ruta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@formadepago", Convert.ToString(aodcformadepago))
        ruta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@acreditacion", Convert.ToString(aodcacreditacion))
        ruta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NotaGeneral", Convert.ToString(aodcobservacionesgrales))
        ruta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@creadopor", Convert.ToString("Martin")) ' debe ir el usuario
        ruta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fechadecreacion", Convert.ToString(Format(DateTime.Now, "dd/MM/yyyy")))
        ruta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FinalizadoPor", Convert.ToString(""))
        ruta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FechaDeFinalizacion", Convert.ToString(""))
        ruta.ExecuteNonQuery()

        MsgBox("Datos ingresados correctamente")

        ' Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
    If Conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        Conn.Close()
        Conn.Dispose()
    End If

End Sub

Sub agregarproducto()

    Dim conn As New SqlConnection
    conn.ConnectionString = conexion

    ruta = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO OrdenesDeCompraEXION (NumeroDeOrden, Item, Producto, Cantidad, iva, preciounitariosiniva, preciounitarioconiva, preciototalsiniva, preciototalconiva, creadopor, editadopor, fechadecreacion, fechadeedicion) values (@NumeroDeOrden, @Item, @Producto, @Cantidad, @iva, @preciounitariosiniva, @preciounitarioconiva, @preciototalsiniva, @preciototalconiva, @creadopor, @editadopor, @fechadecreacion, @fechadeedicion)", conn)

    Dim filas As DataGridViewRowCollection = aodcdt.Rows
    Try
        Conn.Open()

        For i As Integer = 0 To aodcdt.Rows.Count - 1

            ruta.Parameters.Clear()

            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(aodcordendecompra) Then
                ruta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numerodeorden", DBNull.Value)
                ruta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item", DBNull.Value)
            Else
                ruta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numerodeorden", Convert.ToString(aodcordendecompra))
                ruta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item", aodcordendecompra & "-" & i + 1)
            End If

            ruta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@producto", aodcdt.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value)
            ruta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cantidad", aodcdt.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value)
            ruta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@preciounitariosiniva", aodcdt.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value)
            ruta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@preciounitarioconiva", Convert.ToString(aodcdt.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value * (1.0 + (aodciva) / 100)))
            ruta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@preciototalsiniva", aodcdt.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value)
            ruta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iva", Convert.ToString(aodciva))
            ruta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@preciototalconiva", aodcdt.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value)
            ruta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@creadopor", Convert.ToString("Martin")) ' debe ir el nombre del usuario
            ruta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fechadecreacion", Convert.ToString(Format(DateTime.Now, "dd/MM/yyyy")))
            ruta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EditadoPor", Convert.ToString(""))
            ruta.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FechaDeEdicion", Convert.ToString(""))

            ruta.ExecuteNonQuery()



        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
    If Conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        Conn.Close()
        Conn.Dispose()
    End If

End Sub
```

Ingadando en internet me tope con este post

[Enlace a post de StackOverflow con problema parecido](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23448403/the-parameterized-query-expects-the-parameter-units-which-was-not-supp)

Adapte su caso a mi posible inconveniente pero sin embargo el mensaje de `Exception` sigue apareciendo.
 Espero haber sido lo suficientemente claro con mi problema ante cualquier duda intentare responderla lo antes posible

Muchas gracias de ante mano

Comment: Sería interesante que copiaras y pegaras en tu pregunta el texto de la excepción. Por lo demás, felicitarte por la claridad de tu pregunta.

Comment: Tu grilla tiene 2 filas. Una esta vacia. Por eso recibis el error

Comment: Pikoh tenia una duda acerca de si estaba bien ingresar errores en ingles en el titulo de inmediato lo corrijo, Gbianchi pero en el for cuando lo recorro me aseguro que nunca pise esa fila  `For i As Integer = 0 To aodcdt.Rows.Count - 1` porque la lee igual entonces?

Comment: Martin, yo no lo pondría en el título, sino en el cuerpo de tu pregunta. Aunque el titulo me parece que está mejor ahora como lo has puesto :)

Comment: esa grilla tiene 2 filas... la fila para ingresar datos nuevos, existe y esta vacia... vos vas de 0 a count-1 porque esta indexado en cero.. pero si debugueas tu codigo, vas a ver que ese for lo recorre dos veces

Comment: aodcdt.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value comproba que eso no sea vacio al principio y saltate esa fila.. y vas a ver que todo funciona...

Comment: `For i As Integer = 0 To aodcdt.Rows.Count - 1` recorre todas las filas. Si quieres obviar la ultima deberías poner `For i As Integer = 0 To aodcdt.Rows.Count - 2`. Pero creo que sería mejor directamente algo como `If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(aodcordendecompra) Then ..` y metieras ahi el código de inserción con los parámetros, para saltarte de esa manera cualquier fila que sea nula.

Comment: Agradezco mucho la ayuda brindada el error fue solucionado!

Comment: Edite el cuerpo de la pregunta con la solución en la parte superior, si no es contribuyente para la comunidad (al ser un error menor y sucedio por ser lamentablemente insuficientemente abispado) lo mejor seria eliminarlo.

Comment: Aun estoy un poco verde en StackOverflow lo lamento, gracias por la corrección y por la ayuda!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El pasaje de parametros en este caso es correcto.

El problema es que se esta recorriendo la grilla, y no todos los campos de la grilla estan llenos.

En este caso, la causante del error, es que la grilla tiene prendida la propiedad que permite agregar filas nuevas directamente sobre ella. Sin embargo, esa fila existe y se cuenta, por mas que se agregue despues y lo haga la misma grilla.

Entonces, al hacer:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To aodcdt.Rows.Count - 1
```

En realidad, se estan recorriendo dos filas (guiandonos por el ejemplo), la fila que tiene datos, y una que no tiene datos, que es la newrow.

Para evitar estos problemas, lo que hay que hacer es controlar si la fila tiene valor en algun campo, y si no saltearla.

una posible solucion es esta:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To aodcdt.Rows.Count - 1
   If aodcdt.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value <> "" Then
       ....
   end if 
next
```

Y otra forma seria:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To aodcdt.Rows.Count - 1
   If aodcdt.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value <> "" Then
       Continue
   end if 
   ...El codigo si esta todo bien...
next
```

[Continue](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/continue-statement) Se usa para transferir el control de vuelta a la sentencia For en este caso.